# Excel moving rows without affecting formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document where I use 1 sheet as an input tab, and do all calculating in other sheets. The order of the input rows is relevant, as it is basically a route planning system.

Problem that I find is that if I move 1 row in my inputsheet, the formulas in the output sheet adjust accordingly. This prevents me from trying, or at a later moment calculating, the optimal order of rows.

Example: row 5 contains the formulas to calculate traveltimes from row 4 to row 5. Now I switch row 2 to row 5 and want to calculate the traveltimes again. Problem is now the formula in row 5 had adjusted itself to keep refering to the original data, which is now in row 2. Even absolute references do this.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: One possibility is to use `INDEX()`. For example, if column 3 is used in a calculation and your data range is `A2:C6`, then: `=INDEX($A$:$C$6,1,3)-INDEX($A$2:$C$6,2,3)`. So row 1 will always subtract row 2.

Comment: Please show (or post) some if your worksheet. From your description, it is not clear how separated your inputs are from your calculations. Properly separating the two is likely to be part of the solution but without a clearer understanding, any suggested solutions are likely to be less than effective.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

According to your description, I create a simple sample, the formula to calculate the time is `=SUM(INDIRECT("A5:C5"))`.

[image]